# What is wrong with my code? Using split with a string, and assigning the tokens to the fields in a class [ JAVA ]

Tags: java, string, split

The string im passing is this "Tom, Wing Stop, Franklin Mountain,   28, 5, 39.16"

Im passing the string, and assigning the fields in the class to them., Im not sure why im getting this error

```
  public class UberUser{
  String name;
  String pickUp;
  String destination;
  int rideTime;
  int miles;
  double earning;

  public UberUser(String s){
    String line = s;
    s=s.replaceAll("\\s","");

    String tokens[] = s.split(",");   
    this.name = tokens[0];
    this.pickUp = tokens[1];
    this.destination = tokens[2];
    this.rideTime = Integer.parseInt (tokens[3]);
    this.miles = Integer.parseInt (tokens[4]);
    this. earning = Double.parseDouble(tokens[5]);
  }

public class UberTester{
  public static void main (String[]args)throws Exception{

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("uberLog.txt"));
    String str;
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    while((str = in.readLine()) != null){
      list.add(str);
    }

    List<UberUser> users = new ArrayList<UberUser>();
    for(String s :list){
    users.add(new UberUser(s));
    }
  }
}
```

if anybody can help me i would really appreciate it thanks!

this is the error:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
    at UberUser.<init>(UberUser.java:17)
    at UberTester.main(UberTester.java:16)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at edu.rice.cs.drjava.model.compiler.JavacCompiler.runCommand(JavacCompiler.java:267)
```

Comment: The first problem is you haven't included the code in the question.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add the code and any errors, as well as a description of what you're trying to do, inputs etc. Images are not a good way to convey the necessary information.

Comment: Downvoted because of picture as a code.

Comment: Please post your code directly on this site, please. It makes others easy to read and understand to help you, thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Rather than posting a screenshot of your code, please include the complete (but minimal) code directly in the question, along with the error you're seeing.

Comment: The second problem is you haven't included the input, which is probably wrong i.e. you don't have enough commas in your input string.

Comment: I suggest you try adding a breakpoint on that line of code and run it in your debugger to help debug your program.

Comment: @PeterLawrey "you haven't included the input" -> I'm assuming this is what was meant by "Tom, Wing Stop, Franklin Mountain, 28, 5, 39.16".

Comment: @Ricardo as a general principle, parsing input data in a constructor is a bad idea. Parse it in outside the constructor, and pass in separate parameters. Of course, that shifts the same problem to outside the ctor...

Comment: @AndyTurner That was added later, however this isn't the input as when it is used, the code runs fine.

Comment: *Im not sure why im getting this error...* Which error?

Comment: @Ricardo Your code seems to run fine. What is the issue?

Comment: @PeterLawrey [it was in the first version of the question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/53334042/1).

Comment: @AndyTurner and yet the OP gets an error which indicates this is not the actual input.

Comment: Sorry guys ill keep it in mind for next time i ask a question. No more pictures

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're not passing the string in.

```
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    UberUser user = new UberUser("Tom, Wing Stop, Franklin Mountain,  28, 5, 39.16");
    System.out.println(user);
  }
}

class UberUser{
  String name;
  String pickUp;
  String destination;
  int rideTime;
  int miles;
  double earning;

  public UberUser(String s){
    String line = s;
    s=s.replaceAll("\\s","");

    String tokens[] = s.split(",");   
    this.name = tokens[0];
    this.pickUp = tokens[1];
    this.destination = tokens[2];
    this.rideTime = Integer.parseInt (tokens[3]);
    this.miles = Integer.parseInt (tokens[4]);
    this. earning = Double.parseDouble(tokens[5]);
  }

  public String toString() { 
    return String.format("Name: %s\nPick-Up: %s\nDestination: %s\nRide Time: %d\nMiles: %d\nEarning: £%f", name, pickUp, destination, rideTime, miles, earning);
  }
}
```

Gives

```
java version "1.8.0_31"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_31-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.31-b07, mixed mode)

Name: Tom
Pick-Up: WingStop
Destination: FranklinMountain
Ride Time: 28
Miles: 5
Earning: £39.160000
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to split a String using the delimiter `,` Since there is no `,` in your String the Split only returns a single index. which is `tokens[0]`, The problem with your code is you are trying to call `tokens[1]` What I would do is check if the String contains `,` before splitting it. Or check if `tokens.length` is greater then 1.

You can do a simple check by using this code

```
    if(!s.contains(",")){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid String Pattern");
    }
```

Comment: Reason for downvote? The OP asked what is wrong with their code.

Comment: Whilst I haven't downvoted, your answer doesn't actually say anything other than "yep, it's wrong".

Comment: @AndyTurner edited or does this still not explain whats wrong?

Comment: Maybe the OP isn't passing in `,` in the actual code they are testing, because the code the OP provided compiles for me!

Comment: There you go :P

Answer (score 0):

This is where using a debugger is useful as you are not using the input you think you are.

This runs without error.

```
class A {
    static class UberUser {
        String name;
        String pickUp;
        String destination;
        int rideTime;
        int miles;
        double earning;

        public UberUser(String s) {
            String line = s;
            s = s.replaceAll("\\s", "");

            String tokens[] = s.split(",");
            this.name = tokens[0];
            this.pickUp = tokens[1];
            this.destination = tokens[2];
            this.rideTime = Integer.parseInt(tokens[3]);
            this.miles = Integer.parseInt(tokens[4]);
            this.earning = Double.parseDouble(tokens[5]);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new UberUser("Tom, Wing Stop, Franklin Mountain,  28, 5, 39.16");
    }
}
```

As @AndyTurner points out you should be parsing the input before calling the constructor.

```
class A {
    static class UberUser {
        String name;
        String pickUp;
        String destination;
        int rideTime;
        int miles;
        double earning;

        public UberUser(String name, String pickUp, String destination, int rideTime, int miles, double earning) {
            this.name = name;
            this.pickUp = pickUp;
            this.destination = destination;
            this.rideTime = rideTime;
            this.miles = miles;
            this.earning = earning;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "UberUser{" +
                    "name='" + name + '\'' +
                    ", pickUp='" + pickUp + '\'' +
                    ", destination='" + destination + '\'' +
                    ", rideTime=" + rideTime +
                    ", miles=" + miles +
                    ", earning=" + earning +
                    '}';
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String line = "Tom, Wing Stop, Franklin Mountain,  28, 5, 39.16";

        String tokens[] = line.trim().split(" *, *");
        String name = tokens[0];
        String pickUp = tokens[1];
        String destination = tokens[2];
        int  rideTime = Integer.parseInt(tokens[3]);
        int miles = Integer.parseInt(tokens[4]);
        double earning = Double.parseDouble(tokens[5]);
        UberUser user = new UberUser(name, pickUp, destination, rideTime, miles, earning);
        System.out.println(user);
    }
}
```

prints

```
UberUser{name='Tom', pickUp='Wing Stop', destination='Franklin Mountain', rideTime=28, miles=5, earning=39.16}
```